# two isps, two routers, one linux box

Tags: networking

I'm new to IP routing and I'm having difficulty setting up two links. I have a Linux box that's connected to 192.168.1.1 on `eth0` and gets the IP address 192.168.1.135. This is the Internet connection that my box will primarily use. It's also connected to 192.168.8.1 on `eth1` and gets the IP address 192.168.8.100. This Internet connection is a backup, and will only be used to ssh in (or for light tasks). I have been able to make outbound connections over both links.

I want to be able to ssh into the box from both public IP addresses. Currently, I cannot ssh into the box on `eth1`. I presume the issue is because responses to ssh connections on `eth1` are being sent from `eth0`.

In `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, I've added:

```
10 isp
13 gsm
```

And in a shell, I run

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table isp
ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 dev eth1 table gsm
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 # default table
```

What have I missed?

And help would be appreciated!

Comment: Two questions.     1. Did you open the port on your 8.1 router and forwarded to  8.100? 2. Are you able to ssh locally on lan on 8.100 ip?

Comment: I have egg on my face. I think I found the problem. I put another computer on 192.168.8.0/24 and confirmed that I could ssh to 192.168.8.100. I then double checked that I setup port forwarding properly. In the process, I noticed that the WAN ip of the modem was different than what I was getting from ipchicken.com. I realized that my isp has put me behind a NAT of some kind. The computer on the 8.0/24 network can ssh to the WAN-but-not-public address. Thanks for your help SeanClt and Tamadite. I need to have a sit down with my isp and figure out if I can get a public ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I think I was on the right track. Most importantly, I forgot to flush the cache. I solved the problem with:

```
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 tab 1
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 dev eth1 tab 2
$ sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.135/32 tab 1 priority 500
$ sudo ip rule add from 192.168.8.100/32 tab 2 priority 600
$ sudo ip route flush cache
```

I haven't been able to get this solution to with what I have in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, but since the routing is going to be straightforward, I don't care too much for the names.

As always, thanks everybody for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Routing tables other than default *are not used automagically*. You need to set up policy routing rules for that:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.135 lookup isp
ip rule add from 192.168.8.100 lookup gsm
```

(Although you probably don't need the "isp" rule, since your default table already covers that and there's no reason to duplicate everything.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to secure that SSH can accept connections from both interfaces/ip subnets.

For more information please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115893/how-to-enable-two-network-interfaces-both-for-internet-in-ubuntu12-04

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue. The box isn't responding to pings, so I think the issue lies somewhere lower level. For what it's worth, I added ListenAddress 192.168.1.135 ListenAddress 192.168.8.100 to my sshd_config, restarted sshd, and attempted to connect. The connection didn't succeed.

Comment: Please note that not being able to ping is not an indication of a probelm if ICMP packages are not permited to flow thru. In other words, you could have SSH access without being able to ping. The address I gave you provides a debug procedure.